# Macbook Pro 15", backspace not working with VIM?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I just got a new macbook pro 15" in my hands and it seems that for some weird (mapping?) reason, within vim I cannot use backspace (delete character left of the cursor!). However, all other operations including delete (character on right side of cursor which is fn+backspace) work fine!

Anyone has already troubleshooted this weird behaviour?

FYI, the keyboard has the German layout but in software I use the International English layout. On my other laptop (macbook pro 15" but 2010 model - though same software but normal english international physical keyboard layout I never had such an issue)

Comment: IMO it's either backspace or fn+backspace. I have a retina macbook 13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you are running vim in compatible mode.

Create a file called `~/.vimrc` and put the following lines in it.

```
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Setting the backspace option should change the backspace key to behave how you expect it to. However these should be set by the system vimrc on mac.